# Как сделать кастомный tabLayout? Пример на картинке

Tags: android, xml, material-design, customview, android-tablayout

стоит задача переделать дизайн tabLayout по такому примеру - выбранный текст заливается фигурой(темно-фиолетовой), фигура перемещается внутри контура(белого). Возможно ли это сделать(хотя бы приближённо)? Буду благодарен за любые наводки!
[image: пример реализации]

Comment: это мне кажется нужно делать через полностью кастомную вьюху

Comment: Можно попробовать для выделенного tab ставить background в виде shape, и сделать общий shape

Comment: @ArtyMorris , спасибо за подсказку. Но как "для выделенного tab ставить background"? - это основная проблема

Comment: Разобрался, через селектор: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31640563/how-do-i-change-a-tab-background-color-when-using-tablayout